# Get Values from dynamically added HTML elements in C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

I had create controller which should take data from views. Since form should post multiple selects which can be from 1 to many, and selects are dynamically added from JS.
When I post form, my GroupConfigs are 0 even if I had add 3 selects.
Can some one help me ?
The problem is on posting form request.GroupConfigs are always 0.

```
public class CreateGroupConfigViewModel
{
  public int ProductId { get;  set; }
  public int SparePartId { get;  set; }
}
public class CreateGroupViewModel
{
  public CreateGroupViewModel()
  {
    GroupConfigs = new List<CreateGroupConfigViewModel>();
  }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "System Name can not be empty.")]
  public string GroupName { get; set; }

  public List<CreateGroupConfigViewModel> GroupConfigs ;
 

}
  [HttpPost("{plantId}/Create")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int plantId, CreateGroupViewModel request)
  {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      ViewBag.SpareParts = new SelectList(await _sparePartRepository.ListAsync(), "Id", "DisplayedName");
      ViewBag.Products = new SelectList(await _productRepository.ListAsync(), "Id", "DisplayedName");
      CreateGroupViewModel response = new CreateGroupViewModel();
      return View(response);
    }

    var newGroup = await _groupRepository.AddAsync(new Group(request.GroupName, plantId));
    
    return View();
  }
```

And View

```
@model CreateGroupViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Group Page";
}
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="GroupName">System Name:</label>
        <input asp-for="GroupName" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.GroupName)</span>
    </div>
    <div id="productSparePartsContainer">

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.GroupConfigs.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="productSparePart">
                <label >Product:</label>
                <select asp-items="@ViewBag.Products" class="form-control " asp-for="@Model.GroupConfigs[i].ProductId">
                    <option value="0">Select Product</option>
                </select>


                <label for="ProductSpareParts[@i].SparePartId">Spare Part:</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.GroupConfigs[i].SparePartId, ViewBag.SpareParts as SelectList, "Select Spare Part", new { required = "required" })

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeProductSparePart(this)">Remove</button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addProductSparePart()">Insert</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
@section scripts {
    <script>
        function addProductSparePart() {
            var container = document.getElementById('productSparePartsContainer');
            var index = container.children.length;

            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = 'productSparePart';

            var label1 = document.createElement('label');
            label1.htmlFor = 'Model.GroupConfigs[' + index + '].ProductId';
            label1.textContent = 'Product:';
            div.appendChild(label1);

            var select1 = document.createElement('select');
            select1.name = 'GroupConfigs[' + index + '].ProductId';
            select1.setAttribute('asp-for', 'GroupConfigs[' + index + '].ProductId');
            select1.required = true;
            select1.className = 'form-control';
            // Add options dynamically for products
            var products = @Json.Serialize(ViewBag.Products);
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = products[i].value;
                option.text = products[i].text;
                select1.appendChild(option);
            }
            // Add options dynamically for products (similar to spare parts)

            div.appendChild(select1);

            var label2 = document.createElement('label');
            label2.htmlFor = 'GroupConfigs[' + index + '].SparePartId';
            label2.textContent = 'Spare Part:';
            div.appendChild(label2);

            var select2 = document.createElement('select');
            select2.name = 'GroupConfigs[' + index + '].SparePartId';
            select2.required = true;
            select2.className = 'form-control';
            // Add options dynamically for products
            var spareparts = @Json.Serialize(ViewBag.SpareParts);
            for (var i = 0; i < spareparts.length; i++) {
                var optionSpare = document.createElement('option');
                console.log(spareparts[i]);
                optionSpare.value = spareparts[i].value;
                optionSpare.text = spareparts[i].text;
                select2.appendChild(optionSpare);
            }

            div.appendChild(select2);

            var button = document.createElement('button');
            button.type = 'button';
            button.textContent = 'Remove';
            button.className = "btn btn-danger";
            button.onclick = function () {
                container.removeChild(div);
            };

            div.appendChild(button);

            container.appendChild(div);
        }

        function removeProductSparePart(button) {
            var container = document.getElementById('productSparePartsContainer');
            var div = button.parentElement;
            container.removeChild(div);
        }
    </script>
}
enter code here
```